# How/where I can set eslint config file in spacemacs

Tags: configuration, eslint, spacemacs

I have project with eslint already setup and I would like to use it in Spacemacs. Unfortunately Spacemacs seems to ignore .eslintrc.js file in project root.

[image]

[image]

I'm on Windows 10 ...

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spacemacs (and flycheck, the autocompletion plugin that interfaces with eslint) don't look for eslint configs, they delegate that to eslint itself. If you're getting this issue it means eslint itself is erroring out when it tries to load your project config.

Run `eslint --print-config .` from your project directory and resolve all errors it prints out, and that should fix it.

Comment: hmm. Thanks but this is not related with errors in configuration. I can run eslint from terminal and it work correctly. Same with other editors. Only Spacemacs with Flycheck seems to have problem.

Comment: Again, the most recent versions of Flycheck don't check for the config file, they run `eslint --print-config` in the current directory, and check the exit code.

So if running `eslint --print-config .` in your project directory doesn't report any issues, then not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I just removed all packages and installed them again. And now Flycheck works. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm running a mac setup, this is what worked for me:

assuming you've [installed eslint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint#global-installation-and-usage), you can enable [syntax checking](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8e1af145480d53e8d32cdff2c83291889903164b/layers/+checkers/syntax-checking/README.org#install) in your `~/.spacemacs` [file](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/8e1af145480d53e8d32cdff2c83291889903164b/core/templates/.spacemacs.template#L50)

---

Begin by typing `SPC f e d` and uncommenting `syntax-checking`

```
;; spell-checking
syntax-checking
```

- resync your config by typing `SPC f e R`
- open a javascript file in your project, which should have an `.eslintrc` in its root
- type `SPC e v`

From here you can confirm that *javascript-eslint* is enabled and that an `.eslintrc` has been detected for your project.